# Nginx PHP-FPM and curl hangs subsequent browser to server requests

Tags: php, curl, nginx

I have php-fpm & nginx stack installed on my server.

I'm running a JS app which fires an AJAX request that internally connects to a third party service using curl. This service takes a long time to respond say approximately 150s.

Now, When i connect to the same page on another browser tab, it doesn't even return the javascript code on the page which triggers the ajax requests. Basically all subsequent requests keep loading until either the curl returns response or it timeouts.

Here, i have proxy_read_timeout set to 300 seconds.

I want to know why nginx is holding the resource and not serving other clients.

Comment: How many PHP5-FPM workers do you have running? Is the JS application also returned from a PHP script? How does your NGINX config look?

Comment: The Js application is returned from a php script

There are 4 php-fpm workers

Comment: nginx conf

worker_connection 1024
worker_processes 5 

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;

Comment: If that is the case then it is unlikely your request is waiting to be processed by FPM. Something else is hanging it up. You should enable the FPM slow request log, and inspect the nginx access / error logs during the subsequent request following the long AJAX curl request.

Comment: Sure. i'll enable FPM slow request log

Comment: Hi SArnab, the problem was not because of php-fpm or nginx. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was due to the PHP session lock. When i used to make a certain request, PHP used to lock the session file and would release only after the request was completed.

To avoid this, you may use `session_write_close()`. In my case, I implemented redis session.

Problem solved!!!

Comment: Good to know! How'd you discover this

Comment: I created a PHP page and added sleep(100). While this was executing, I requested same url on next tab which was returning result. This prompted me to add session_start() before the sleep(100).

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem as well. I am running everything with docker. Nginx at the front as a gateway to multiple docker "sites". Then one of the sites are running nginx + php-fpm8. Added this at the start of my long running php script and now everything runs ok for the other users.